# How can I open a document from a display form in modern experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern

I have created a document library and a list. The library has a lookup column to the list.
I have added a document to the library. From the list, a click on the item for the lookup column and display form opens. If I am in modern experience, I do not have the possibility to open the document. The field Name does not have a link.
But when I am in classic experience I can open the document, the field name has a link.
How can I open the document from the modern experience?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add a json format in your list?If you add a json format,you'd better share your json format.

When I test, no matter what kind of page the file is clickable, the difference in file type will lead to whether the file is opened or downloaded.